# datatable ajax colour changing of rows based on condition in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatable

Hi guys I have a datatable loading from ajax.
I need to change the row color against some condition.
 script like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataTable =  $('#example').DataTable( {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "ajax.php" // json datasource

        } );
  } );
```

HTML like this

```
<table id="example" >
<thead>
<tr>
 <th>#</th>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>

</table>
```

In ajax.php

```
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
$nestedData=array();
$nestedData[] = $i;
$nestedData[] = $row["id"];
$nestedData[] = $row["name"];
$nestedData[] = $row["status"];
$data[] = $nestedData;
$i++;
}

$json_data = array(
"draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw.
"recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
"recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
"data"            => $data   // total data array
);

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
```

It works but what i need is to change the row color according to status.
if status==1 then yellow , if status==2 then red , if status==3 then blue.how i add this table row color in this type of format.

Comment: after data table load you can use each loop function and get status column value  by each row and check it's column value and compare your condition and it's satisfied then changed color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use "fnRowCallback" as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable =  $('#example').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "ajax.php",
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            if ( aData[3] == "1" )
            {
            $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Yellow');
            }
            else if ( aData[3] == "2" )
            {
            $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
            }
            else if ( aData[3] == "3" )
            {
            $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Blue');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what if i dont need to display status and need the same result?

Comment: Add this `"columnDefs": [{ "visible": false, "targets": 3 }]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ):